# Prestashop Back Office change filter position in Orders

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am using prestashop 1.7.3 and I have added Tracking number filter on orders list page BUT it is just after the filtter for Refference number. How can I move filtter tracking number after the filtter for order status **(Please, check the screenshot attached)**

My code is located in: /override/controllers/admin/AdminOrdersController.php

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2SPY.jpg)

```
   <?php

class AdminOrdersController extends AdminOrdersControllerCore
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        $this->table = 'order';
        $this->className = 'Order';
        $this->lang = false;
        $this->addRowAction('view');
        $this->explicitSelect = true;
        $this->allow_export = true;
        $this->deleted = false;

        parent::__construct();

        $this->_select = '
        a.id_currency,
        a.id_order AS id_pdf,
        CONCAT(c.`firstname`, \' \', c.`lastname`) AS `customer`,
        c.email AS `email`,
        address.phone `phone`,
        osl.`name` AS `osname`,
        os.`color`,
        IF((SELECT so.id_order FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'orders` so WHERE so.id_customer = a.id_customer AND so.id_order < a.id_order LIMIT 1) > 0, 0, 1) as new,
        country_lang.name as cname,
        IF(a.valid, 1, 0) badge_success';

        $this->_join = '
        INNER JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'order_carrier` oc ON a.`id_order` = oc.`id_order`
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'customer` c ON (c.`id_customer` = a.`id_customer`)
        INNER JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'address` address ON address.id_address = a.id_address_delivery
        INNER JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'country` country ON address.id_country = country.id_country
        INNER JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'country_lang` country_lang ON (country.`id_country` = country_lang.`id_country` AND country_lang.`id_lang` = '.(int)$this->context->language->id.')
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'order_state` os ON (os.`id_order_state` = a.`current_state`)
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'order_state_lang` osl ON (os.`id_order_state` = osl.`id_order_state` AND osl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$this->context->language->id.')';
        $this->_orderBy = 'id_order';
        $this->_orderWay = 'DESC';
        $this->_use_found_rows = true;

        $statuses = OrderState::getOrderStates((int)$this->context->language->id);
        foreach ($statuses as $status) {
            $this->statuses_array[$status['id_order_state']] = $status['name'];
        }

        $this->fields_list = array(
            'id_order' => array(
                'title' => $this->trans('ID', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
                'align' => 'text-center',
                'class' => 'fixed-width-xs'
            ),
            'reference' => array(
                'title' => $this->trans('Reference', array(), 'Admin.Global')
            ),
             'tracking_number' => array(
                     'title' => $this->l('tracking number'),
                             'havingFilter' => true,
        ),
            /*
            'new' => array(
                'title' => $this->trans('New client', array(), 'Admin.Orderscustomers.Feature'),
                'align' => 'text-center',
                'type' => 'bool',
                'tmpTableFilter' => true,
                'orderby' => false,
            ),
            */
            'customer' => array(
                'title' => $this->trans('Customer', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
                'havingFilter' => true,
            ),
            'phone' => array(
                'title' => $this->trans('Phone', array(), 'Admin.Global')
            ),
            'email' => array(
                'title' => $this->trans('Email', array(), 'Admin.Global')
            ),
        );

        if (Configuration::get('PS_B2B_ENABLE')) {
            $this->fields_list = array_merge($this->fields_list, array(
                'company' => array(
                    'title' => $this->trans('Company', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
                    'filter_key' => 'c!company'
                ),
            ));
        }

        $this->fields_list = array_merge($this->fields_list, array(
            'total_paid_tax_incl' => array(
                'title' => $this->trans('Total', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
                'align' => 'text-right',
                'type' => 'price',
                'currency' => true,
                'callback' => 'setOrderCurrency',
                'badge_success' => true
            ),
            'payment' => array(
                'title' => $this->trans('Payment', array(), 'Admin.Global')
            ),
            'osname' => array(
                'title' => $this->trans('Status', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
                'type' => 'select',
                'color' => 'color',
                'list' => $this->statuses_array,
                'filter_key' => 'os!id_order_state',
                'filter_type' => 'int',
                'order_key' => 'osname'
            ),
            'date_add' => array(
                'title' => $this->trans('Date', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
                'align' => 'text-right',
                'type' => 'datetime',
                'filter_key' => 'a!date_add'
            )
        ));
        /* 
        if (Country::isCurrentlyUsed('country', true)) {
            $result = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->ExecuteS('
            SELECT DISTINCT c.id_country, cl.`name`
            FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'orders` o
            '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('orders', 'o').'
            INNER JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'address` a ON a.id_address = o.id_address_delivery
            INNER JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'country` c ON a.id_country = c.id_country
            INNER JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'country_lang` cl ON (c.`id_country` = cl.`id_country` AND cl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$this->context->language->id.')
            ORDER BY cl.name ASC');

            $country_array = array();
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                $country_array[$row['id_country']] = $row['name'];
            }

            $part1 = array_slice($this->fields_list, 0, 3);
            $part2 = array_slice($this->fields_list, 3);
            $part1['cname'] = array(
                'title' => $this->trans('Delivery', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
                'type' => 'select',
                'list' => $country_array,
                'filter_key' => 'country!id_country',
                'filter_type' => 'int',
                'order_key' => 'cname'
            );
            $this->fields_list = array_merge($part1, $part2);
        }
        */
        $this->shopLinkType = 'shop';
        $this->shopShareDatas = Shop::SHARE_ORDER;

        if (Tools::isSubmit('id_order')) {
            // Save context (in order to apply cart rule)
            $order = new Order((int)Tools::getValue('id_order'));
            $this->context->cart = new Cart($order->id_cart);
            $this->context->customer = new Customer($order->id_customer);
        }

        $this->bulk_actions = array(
            'updateOrderStatus' => array('text' => $this->trans('Change Order Status', array(), 'Admin.Orderscustomers.Feature'), 'icon' => 'icon-refresh')
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved it cycling the field_list array and rebuilding it into different array, so in my override i put this code just before closing the constructor function in this way

```
class AdminOrdersController extends AdminOrdersControllerCore
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
           /* Your code */


            $fileds = array();

            foreach ($this->fields_list as $key => $value) {
                $fileds[$key] = $value;
                if ($key == 'current_state') {

                    $fileds['tracking_number'] = array(
                       'title' => $this->l('tracking number'),
                       'havingFilter' => true,
                  );
             }

            $this->fields_list = $fileds;
        }


    }
}
```

this works in my case